# Specify your own choice Column

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, csom, jquery-ui

I want to store text entered in Choice Field ("Specify your own value") in to another column. For example . I have a drop down with Choice Fields (A,B,C) and with one Specify your own value . If a user enters in the Text box of choice field ("Specify your own value") it has to save different column instead of choice .

Comment: "it has to save different column instead of choice ."  So, if user picks A, B or C, then all done. No update to any other column needed? If they type a value, the value needs to be copied to another column? Should the text be left in the dropdown's text box, or blanked?

Comment: Yes it has to save in different column ,Actually i want to color code only the values entered in "Specify your own value" so i thought it would be easy if we can store in different column

Answer (score 0):

If you are permitted to use SharePoint Designer workflows, you could do something like this:

- Add a Set Field in Current Item action. Set the Field to your Single Line of Text column and the value to your Choice column.
- Set the workflow to start on Created and Changed.

See here for the color coding / HTML workarounds using a workflow: http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2018/01/adding-html-to-sharepoint-columns-color.html

Comment: i will give you a try

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to show or hide the `other value column` (which you want to store user's custom value) when certain value of choice is selected, to do so:

**First** , in the choice column  set `Allow 'Fill-in' choices`: to `No`
add another choice for other value , *i.e.Other*

**Second** 
add script to handle the input field visibility

> - In the new item form, edit page
> - Add `content editor` web part
> - click on edit source and use the below script
> - when the `Other` value is select the `Other input field` will be visible, else  the input field will be hidden

```
​​<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

  //replace OtherfieldName with your field name
  $('nobr:contains("OtherfieldName")').closest('tr').hide();

  // replace choicecolwith you choice column name
  $("select[title='choicecol']").change(function() {
  if ($("select[title='choicecol']").val() == "Other") {

           $('nobr:contains("OtherfieldName")').closest('tr').show();
       } 

  else {
         $('nobr:contains("OtherfieldName")').closest('tr').hide();

      }
 });

</script>​​
```

Comment: But my question is how can i color code the value entered in text box

Comment: @sandy143 your question is how to save user's custom choice in another column and above is a solution to achieve that